# nib objects aren't changing at runtime

Tags: ios, uibutton

Hello i have a nib file which contains 3 UIButtons , i need to change the attributes of button at runtime after loading from nib but i don't know what am i doing wrong. I have also NSlog after changing the booleans but i always get '0' in output. Any help thx

```
-(void)SettingBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn =(UIButton*)sender;
    UITableViewCell *btncell =(UITableViewCell *)[btn superview];

    if ([[recentActivities objectAtIndex:btn.tag] isKindOfClass:[MeetingSummary class]]) {

        [MainManager getSharedInstance].Summary = [recentActivities objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
        MeetingSummary *ms=[recentActivities objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
        Meeting *m=ms.meeting;


        if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
            lastPoint = sender;
            if (![m.endedDate isEqualToString:@"1/1/0001"]) {

                if (settingpop) {
                    [settingpop release];
                }
                settingpop = [[SettingsPopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsPopViewController" bundle:nil];
                settingpop.start.hidden=YES;
                settingpop.start.enabled=NO;
                NSLog(@"%i",settingpop.start.hidden);
                NSLog(@"%i",settingpop.start.enabled);
                settingpop.btnShowDetail.enabled=NO;
                settingpop.btnShowDetail.hidden=YES;
        //        [settingpop.start removeFromSuperview];
        //        [settingpop.btnShowDetail removeFromSuperview];
                settingpop.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 54);

            }
            else
            {

                settingpop = [[SettingsPopViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsPopViewController" bundle:nil];

            }
            settingpop.delegate = self;
            [settingpop setActivityView:self.view];

            popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:settingpop] retain];

            [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(250.0f, 162.0f)];

            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:btncell
                         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        }else{

            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the row:

```
settingpop.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 54);
```

before the row:

```
settingpop.start.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: 1 thing more when the frame size isn't decreasing of the view

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about adjusting the properties of the `start` and `btnShowDetail` controls of `SettingsPopViewController`? You cannot access its controls immediately after the `initWithNibName`. You have to wait until after the view has been created, i.e., wait until after `viewDidLoad` is called, because the NIB may well not have been loaded until then.

Comment: or force the view of the popover... id v = settingsPop.view